# How to read input in C

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to read a line with `scanf("%[^\n]")`; right before it I'm reading an integer with "%d", was told to me that scanf doesn't erase the '\n' after reading, so I have to call fflush() to avoid it, but even doing that I still have the same problems, so here is my code:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
fflush(stdin);

lines = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*n);

for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    lines[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*1001);
}

for(i = 0;i < n;i++){
    scanf("%[^\n]", linhes[i]);
}
```

I read an integer and then the scanf doesn't wait, it starts reading the input — doesn't matter what the integer value is, whether 5 or 10, the scanf reads all the strings to empty. Already tried with fgets and the result is almost the same, except that it reads some of the strings and skips others.

Comment: try `"%[^\n]"` change to `" %[^\n]"`

Comment: Yeah, I believe it's better to use `fgets` for C anyways... But, I've found that `scanf("\n5d", &variable)` worked well for me during my C classes.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]", lines[i]);` never consumes the `\n`.  Use `fgets()`.

Comment: BLUEPIXY was right, thanks now it works :s

Comment: @BLUEPIXY just mimicking OP's `scanf("%[^\n]", linhes[i]);`

Comment: @VermillionAzure `scanf("\n%d", &variable)` does just about the same as `scanf("%d", &variable)` as `scanf(" %5d", &variable)`.  That leading  white-space does not gain code much.    (note: certain your `5` was ` `%`.

Comment: @chux ...This is why I program C++. This is why I'm blind. I cannot C.

Comment: And `fflush(stdin)` is undefined according to the standard.

Comment: Note what it says in [Using `fflush(stdin)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).  Some platforms define the behaviour of `fflush(stdin)`, but the C standard and POSIX do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us look at this step by step:

> "... read a line with scanf("%[^\n]");".

`scanf("%[^\n]", buf)` does not read a line.  It almost does - sometimes.  `"%[^\n]"` directs `scanf()` to read any number of non-`'\n'` `char` until one is encountered (that `'\n'` is then put back into `stdin`) or EOF occurs.

This approach has some problems:

1. If the first `char` is `'\n'`, `scanf()` puts it back into `stdin` without changing `buf` in anyway! `buf` is left as is - perhaps **uninitialized**.  `scanf()` then returns 0.
2. If at least one non-`'\n'` is read, it is saved into `buf` and more `char` until a `'\n'` occurs.  A `'\0'` is appended to `buf` and the  `'\n'` is put back into `stdin` and `scanf()` returns 1.  This unlimited-ness can easily **overfill** `buf`. If no `char` was saved and `EOF` or input error occurs, `scanf()` returns `EOF`.
3. **Always check the return value of `scanf()`/`fgets()`, etc. functions**.  If your code does not check it, the state of `buf` is unknown.

In any case, a `'\n'` is still usually left in `stdin`, thus the *line* was not fully read.  This  `'\n'` often is an issue for the *next* input function.

> ...  scanf doesn't erase the '\n' after reading

Another common misconception.  `scanf()` reads a `'\n'`, or not, depending on the supplied format.  Some formats consume `'\n'`, others do not.

> ...  call fflush() to avoid it

`fflush(stdin)` is well defined in some compilers but is not in the C standard.  The usual problem is code wants to eliminate any remaining data in `stdin`.  A common alternative, when the end of the line had not yet occurred, is to read and dispose until `'\n'` is found:

```
int ch;  // Use int
while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

> I still have the same problems

The best solution, IMO, is to read a *line* of user input and then scan it.

```
char buf[sizeof lines[i]];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) return NoMoreInput();

// If desired, remove a _potential_ trailing \n
buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;

strcpy(lines[i], buf);
```

I recommend that a buffer should be about 2x the size of expected input for typical code.  Robust code, not this snippet, would detect if more of the line needs to be read.  IMO, such excessively long lines are more often a sign of hackers and not legitimate use.

Comment: when ur program expect a line and there is a limit, and when this limit is reached i think that the rest of the line can be discarded, the best way to do it is to create your own functions(using fgetc) to handle it, and avoid wasting time with learning about those functions. In my case was a program to marathon training so i didn't want to create this functions, and yet i created to test, worked well

Answer (score 0):

BLUEPIXY in the comment answered my question:

> try `"%[^\n]"` change to `" %[^\n]"`